# Quit signal when waiting for blocking read from queue.Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking, locks

In many cases I have a worker thread which pops data from a Queue and acts on it. At some kind of event I want my worker thread to stop. The simple solution is to add a *timeout* to the *get* call and check the *Event*/flag every time the *get* times out. This however as two problems:

- Causes an unnecessary context switch
- Delays the shutdown until a timeout occurs

Is there any better way to listen both to a stop event and new data in the Queue? Is it possible to listen to two Queue's at the same time and block until there's data in the first one? (In this case one can use a second Queue just to trigger the shutdown.)

The solution I'm currently using:

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Event, Thread
from time import sleep

def worker(exit_event, queue):
    print("Worker started.")
    while not exit_event.isSet():
        try:
            data = queue.get(timeout=10)
            print("got {}".format(data))
        except Empty:
            pass
    print("Worker quit.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit_event = Event()
    queue = Queue()

    th = Thread(target=worker, args=(exit_event, queue))
    th.start()

    queue.put("Testing")
    queue.put("Hello!")

    sleep(2)

    print("Asking worker to quit")
    exit_event.set()
    th.join()

    print("All done..")
```

Comment: Can you post the shutdown signal to the one queue? This is how I have done these.  Could you post in the queue a more structured message, like WORK <data> and EXIT and then in your worker branch based on the keyword? You will need to do a little bit of parsing there but if the only thing needed is to check the first bytes, it should not be too onerous.

Comment: Or if you want to write bad code, use your exit event but check it immediately after you have read from the queue and before processing any data, and then post gobbledygook there as it will not be processed anymore - you only post data to make the thread progress from queue.get()

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may easily reduce `timeout` to 0.1...0.01 sec. Slightly different solution is to use the queue to send both data and control commands to the thread:

```
import queue
import threading
import time

THREADSTOP = 0


class ThreadControl:
    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command


def worker(q):
    print("Worker started.")
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if isinstance(data, ThreadControl):
            if data.command == THREADSTOP:
                break
        print("got {}".format(data))
    print("Worker quit.")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = queue.Queue()

    th = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q,))
    th.start()

    q.put("Testing")
    q.put("Hello!")

    time.sleep(2)

    print("Asking worker to quit")
    q.put(ThreadControl(command=THREADSTOP))  # sending command

    th.join()

    print("All done..")
```

Another option is to use sockets instead of queues.